# Better way of doing this slide up panel?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I created a slide up log in/out box and I'm thinking there is a smarter way to do it. The issue I have with it is that it throws a vertical scrollbar on the body when the box appears. This is obviously expected, but short of putting an overflow:hidden on the body, how can I do this more cleanly?

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/43dog4fw/

```
// show logout box    
$('.user').click(function() {
    $('.logout-box')
        .show()
        .animate({
            marginBottom: "0"
        }, 200, 'swing');
});

// Close logout box
$('.close-bar').click(function() {
    $('.logout-box').animate({
        marginBottom: "-=380px"
    }, 200, 'swing', function() {
        $('.logout-box').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Use height instead of margin to animate.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of animating the bottom margin, animate the bottom property in percentage. This way the height of the modal doesn't matter.

**JS**

```
$('.user').click(function() {
    $('.logout-box')
        .show()
        .animate({
            bottom: "0%"
        }, 200, 'swing');
});

// Close logout box
$('.close-bar').click(function() {
    $('.logout-box').animate({
        bottom: "-100%"
    }, 200, 'swing', function() {
        $('.logout-box').hide();
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.logout-box {
  position: fixed;
  background: gray;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -100%;
  height: 380px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000000;
}
```

If your modal always comes up from the bottom of the screen you can change the position to `fixed` instead of `absolute`, this also gets rid of the scroll bar.

[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/43dog4fw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use height instead of margin to animate .

```
// show logout box  
$('.user').click(function() {
  $('.logout-box')
    .show()
    .animate({
    height: "380px"
  }, 200, 'swing');
});
// Close logout box
$('.close-bar').click(function() {
  $('.logout-box').animate({
    height: 0
  }, 200, 'swing', function() {
    $('.logout-box').hide();
  });
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/2e2fgh6c/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use css `transition` and toggle `.visible` class like this:

Check the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/43dog4fw/5/)

```
body { overflow:hidden }
.logout-box {
  position: absolute;
  background: gray;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 380px;
  margin-bottom: -380px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000000;
  opacity:0;
  transition:all 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.visible {
  margin-bottom:0;
  opacity:1;
}
```